# SQL Server Performance Issue while Selecting all records?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What are techniques improve the performance of a query if we are not implementing any filter on it ?
For me 36 Million records (11 GB) with 20 column is taking 11 minutes to pull all records from the table.
is it a sensible time ?
Does index help me to improve performance ?
I am using SQL 2008 Server.
Any techniques to bring down the time ?

Comment: index won't help if there isn't any filter. do you pull the entire table? all records with all columns? if so: why?

Comment: if you are pulling entire table, you will need to minimize disk access..one way is to use INMemory OLTP

Comment: I am using this as a data layer for my visualization, the visualization tool pull the entire data to their memory. So I am just making sure the time took to load is reasonable or is there something to do in DB side ?

Comment: If you pulled all data out into your applications memory (local or on same server?), then in my experience 11 minutes is probably not way off. I guess that is the reason to put it in memory to begin with, so that your tool then tries to optimize, so that it will run fast once in memory?

Comment: This is the time which take to execute the query in SQL, I was just thinking if this can be improved by upgrading the system or doing any optimization..

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know which language you are using. You may be able to CHUNK the data reads in parallel across several threads

> e.g. 10 threads each set to read 3.6 million records.

Or, depending on how your data is structured, you may then be able to use indexes or keys to allow each thread to read data in a specific range

> e.g. Thread 1 reads values for 2017, Thread 2 reads values for 2016 etc

This approach has worked for me previously using MS SQL Server and partitioned views